# How to submit login credentials?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

This is relating to the submit button of the login screen

HTML:

```
<TD background=/frontend/images/greenback.gif width=302><INPUT type=submit value="Login now" name=submit> </TD>
```

I enter the username and password into the box but the script stops at `.Submit`

```vb
Sub GetTable()

'Kills any open IE windows.
On Error GoTo Ignore
Call IE_Sledgehammer
Ignore:

Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim ieTable As Object
Dim clip As DataObject
Dim UserName As String, Password As String

'Create anew instance of ie
Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

'Debugging
ieApp.Visible = True

'Opening this page prompts login screen
ieApp.Navigate "CANNOT SHARE, INTERNAL WORK SITE"

'When busy - wait
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

'Pop up window
On Error GoTo skip_Popup
ieApp.Document.all.item("submitBn").Focus
SendKeys "~"
skip_Popup:

'Login script
On Error GoTo Skip_Login
Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document

'fill in the login form – View Source from your browser to get the control names
With ieDoc.forms(0)
    .UserName.Value = "test1"
    .Password.Value = "test2"
    .Submit
End With

Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
Skip_Login:

'Copy page Info
Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
Set ieTable = ieDoc.all.item

'Copy Paste the page
If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
    Set clip = New DataObject
    clip.SetText "" & ieTable.outerHTML & ""
    clip.PutInClipboard

    'Location of data
    Sheets("Raw Data").Range("E2").PasteSpecial "text"
End If

'Delete any form controls that make it into the sheet
Sheets("Raw Data").DrawingObjects.Delete

'Kills ALL IE windows
Call IE_Sledgehammer
Set ieApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Also this is not critical, how do I just select the table on the page and not everything else? It doesn't have a name so I am stuck with this one also.

HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" align="center" border="0" width="400">
```

Comment: Can you provide the xPath to `Submit` button? For the table, can you not get table elements on the page?

Comment: what does stops mean? Is there an error?

Answer (score 0):

Try using attribute = value css selector

```
ie.document.querySelector("[name=submit]").click
```

For your table your best bet is to locate it by it's relationship to other elements/attributes. Impossible to advise further without seeing more html. Failing that if there is a unique attribute or attribute=value in that table (not present in other tables) then combine that to id the table

e.g.

```
ie.document.querySelector("table[width='400']")
```

This is a less robust method.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and I am able to produce the issue.

As an alternative, you can try to loop through input elements and try to find the submit and click it.

```
 Set objCollection = ieApp.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

    i = 0
    While i < objCollection.Length

            If objCollection(i).Type = "submit" And _
               objCollection(i).Name = "submit" Then


                objCollection(i).Click

            End If

        i = i + 1
    Wend
```